# What is "where T : class" in C# generic methods?

Tags: c#, generics

What is the difference between these method signatures?

```
public void T MyMethod<T>(T parameter)
```

and

```
public void T MyMethod<T>(T parameter) where T : class
```

They seem to have the same result ... so what does `where T : class` do?

Comment: What is unclear about [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the second method the T can only be a class and cannot be a structure type.

See [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> where T : class
>
> *The type argument must be a reference [class] type*; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Answer (score 6):

in the first one you can call it with a non ref type for example

```
MyMethod<int>(10);
```

that will not work with the second version as it only accepts ref types!

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference, but T is restricted to a reference-type.
they differ only at compiletime, as the compiler checks wether T is a ref-type or not.

Comment: So then there *is* a difference ;-) I wonder if they emit the same IL (e.g. is that information kept?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Both won't compile. You should use either `void` or `T`.
2. And second method won't work for `MyMethod(1)` because it requires reference type to `T`